# Row actions for custom post types?

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-admin, filters

I'm working on a plugin, which converts a site into a feedback sort of portal. I made a new object page, 'Feedbacks', which displays all the feedbacks is a tabular format, and I'm using `register_column_headers($array_of_column_headers)` to make my table. I wanted to know if it is possible to add my own page row actions to this table, i mean under every feedback in the list, actions like 'approve', 'delete', 'blacklist' etc.

I read the code and a couple of tickets, and found out its done this way: for posts, its `post_row_actions`, for comments its `comment_row_actions`, for media its `media_row_actions` and so on. Is there a filter that allows me to do, `my-page-slug_row_actions`?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

When using custom post type you use the `post_row_actions` filter hook and check the post type to modify it only:

```
add_filter('post_row_actions','my_action_row', 10, 2);

function my_action_row($actions, $post){
    //check for your post type
    if ($post->post_type =="feedbacks"){
        /*do you stuff here
        you can unset to remove actions
        and to add actions ex:
        $actions['in_google'] = '<a href="http://www.google.com/?q='.get_permalink($post->ID).'">check if indexed</a>';
        */
    }
    return $actions;
}
```

**Quick update:**

thanks to somatic
if you custom post type is "hierarchical" then you action hook is:
`page_row_actions`.

Comment: Does `$post` have scope? *hint hint* ;)

Comment: @t310s Fixed @Bainternet hope you don't mind ,)

Comment: @kaiser: And improved your fix!

Comment: Hi, I already used 'post_row_actions' for adding a link in the the custom posts rows. But I want to do it for my menu page, which is added using 'add_object_page' hook (which is similar to 'add_menu_page'). 

`add_object_page("Feedbacks", "Feedbacks", 10, "feedbacks-menu", "FeedbackMenuFunction");
 add_submenu_page("feedbacks-menu", "Pending Feedbacks", "Pending", 10, "pending-feedbacks-menu", "PendingFeedbackMenuFunction")`

I was wondering if I could do, 'feedbacks-menu_row_actions(...)' (just like its done for other pages like 'Posts', 'Comments' etc using the page slug with row actions).

Comment: Is feedback a custom post type? If so read my answer again.

Comment: Nope! 'Feedback' is a comment on a custom post, along with a whole lotta metadata for that comment! I'm building a whole new section with all these 'Feedbacks' listed in one place, from where the user can Preview them, approve and unapprove them, delete them. Its similar to the 'Comments' page, but custom designed only to show 'Feedback's.

And I found out how to add the row_actions to these rows. Its just the mark-up, `<td><div class='row-actions'><span class='edit'><a...>Your Link</a></span></div></td>`. WP adds the CSS and jQuery and you have the actions menu ready!

Comment: for those of you banging your head on your desk wondering why this code seems to do nothing with your custom post type, note: if your CPT is "hierarchical", then your filter hook is `"page_row_actions"` and NOT `"post_row_actions"`

[rubs head]

Comment: I had tried page_row_actions with my custom menu page's slug, but it doesn't work, or maybe I missed something. But I went through the code of a very famous premium plugin that adds custom page row actions, and saw that they're adding the markup directly to the table. I did the same and it works superfine.